# Smallest dimension of a hyperplane containg 2 hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

> The hyperplanes $H_1$ and $H_2$ have dimension $p$ and $q$, respectively. What is the smallest dimension which the hyperplane $H_3$ must have in order to be sure to contain both $H_1$ and $H_2$?

Here, a hyperplane is defined to be a set of the form $x+L$ where $L$ is a subspace and $x$ is a vector. The answer is $p+q+1$ unless the dimension of $H_3$ exceeds the dimension of the whole space. However, I am not sure why this is the case.

How about the case for the hyperplane containing $k$ number of hyperplanes?

I tried visualizing in 3D, but even that got complicated (in drawing).

Answer (score 1):

This question must have gotten slightly damaged in the transcription. Consider, in 3-space, the line through $(-1, 0, 0)$ in the $(0,1,0)$ direction as $H_1$, and the point $(3,3,3)$ as $H_2$. The claim is that if $H_3$ has dimension $1 + 0 + 1 = 2$, then it is sure to contain $H_1$ and $H_2$. That's simply false, as the $yz$-plane has dimension $2$ but contains neither $H_1$ nor $H_2$.

Probably the correct form of the question is rather messier, and looks something like this: "For each pair of hyperplanes $H_1$ and $H_2$ of dimensions $p$ and $q$ respectively, there's a smallest hyperplane $Q(H_1, H_2)$ containing both. What is $\max(\dim Q(H_1, H_2) )$ over all hyperplanes $H_1$ and $H_2$ of the specified dimensions?"

(An interesting related exercise, as a warmup, is "What is $\min \dim Q(H_1, H_2)$?", but I'll leave that for beginners to think about.)

The secret in this situation is to think about embedding your hyperplanes is a slightly higher dimension, which reduces the problem to one about vector subspaces.

Step 1: Let's suppose we're working in $\Bbb R^n$. Then add an extra coordinate to get $E = \Bbb R^{n+1} = \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R$, and for a hyperplane $H$ in $R^n$, define 
$$
J(H) = \{ (tx, t) \mid x \in H, t \in \Bbb R \}
$$
It's not hard to check that $J(H)$ is a vector subspace of $E$, and $\dim(J(H) = \dim H + 1$. Furthermore, $J$ is a one-to-one mapping between subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$ and subspaces of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ that are not entirely contained in $\Bbb R^n \times \{0\}$ (or, alternatively, subspaces that meet $\Bbb R^n \times \{1\}$).  [You should check these claims!]

Example: If $n = 2$ and $L$ is the line $x + y = 1$, then $J(L)$ is the plane through the origin in 3-space that contains the line $x + y = 1, z = 1$. In short, we put $R^2$ into $R^3$ as the $z = 1$ plane, and then connect every point $P$ of our subspace to the origin by including all multiples $tP$ for any $t \in \Bbb R$.

Now the question becomes: we've got subspaces $A$ and $B$ (instead of $H_1$ and $H_2$, which are a pain to write) and a minimal subspace $C$ containing them. We apply $J$ to get vector subspaces (of $R^{n+1}$!) that we'll call $A' = J(A), B' = J(B), C' = J(C)$, with $\dim A' = p + 1$ and $\dim B' = q + 1$.

What choice of $A'$ and $B'$ will make $\dim C'$ as large as possible?

Let's think about a simple case: what choice of two lines-through-the-origin in 3-space will make the largest subspace containing both? Answer: choosing them non-parallel! In that case, you need a plane to contain both, while if the two lines are parallel, then they are actually identical, and you can contain both in a line.

Back to $A'$ and $B'$: pick a basis for each, say $v_1, \ldots, v_{p+1}$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_{q+1}$. To contain both $A'$ and $B'$, the space $C'$ must contain the span of *all* these vectors. If the vectors are all independent, then $\dim C'  \ge (p+1) + (q+1)$. But a minimal choice for $C'$ is simply $$
span(v_1, \ldots, v_{p+1}, w_1, \ldots, w_{q+1})
$$
which has dimension *exactly* $p+1 + q+1$.

There's a slight hitch here: we find the largest $C'$ when all the vectors are independent, but what if there are too many of them? What if $p+1 + q+1 > n+1$? Then the dimension of $C'$ can be forced to be as large as $n+1$ (i.e., $C$ is all of $E$), but no larger.

So the summary is that

$$
\dim C' \le \min(n+1, (p+1) + (q+1))
$$
and that by picking $A'$ to be the span of $e_1, \ldots e_p$, and $B'$ to be the span of $e_{n+1}, e_n, \ldots, e_{n+1-q}$, we get that $dim C'$ is exactly the value given. (You might object to the fact that $A'$ lies entirely in the $Bbb R^n$ subspace of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, and you're right. If we change the last basis vector of $A$ to $e_p + e_{n+1}$, this problem goes away.)

What's that say about $\dim C$? It's one less than $\dim C'$, so 
$$
\dim C = \min (n, p + q + 1).
$$

and that's the theorem you wanted to prove.

Working through this in every possible case that you can visualize with $n = 1$ or $2$ (i.e., $(p,q) = (0,0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)$) will help make it all make sense.

Answer (score 0):

For any hyperplane $H \subseteq \mathbb R^n,$ the set of vectors you obtain by taking differences between all pairs of vectors in $H$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n.$
(It is the same subspace you get by translating $H$ onto the origin and it is parallel to $H$.)
The dimension of the hyperplane $H$ is the number of vectors in the basis of that subspace.

Another way to put it is that any hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$ can be written $v+S$ where $v\in \mathbb R^n$ and $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n.$

If we have two hyperplanes $H_1=v_1+S_1$ and $H_2=v_2+S_2$
such that the subspaces $S_1$ (with $p$ dimensions) and $S_2$ (with $q$ dimensions) are completely independent and the vector $v_2-v_1$ is independent of both subspaces,
then one can show that any vector between the hyperplanes is a linear combination of the bases of the two subspaces and the vector $v_2-v_1,$
and if any vectors are omitted from that set of $p+q+1$ vectors,
the span of the remaining vectors covers only a proper subset of the vectors between the two hyperplanes.

The minimal hyperplane containing $H_1$ and $H_2$ is therefore $v_1+t(v_2-v_1)+S_1+S_2,$ which has $p+q+1$ dimensions.

An example of this in $\mathbb R^3$ is two skew lines, that is, non-parallel non-intersecting lines.